# Can I download PlayStation 3 games for my PlayStation 4

Tags: ps3, ps4, psn

I want to download a game on PlayStation store with my PlayStation 4 but I noticed it said "PlayStation 3" at the end of the chart.

Does that mean that it can't be run on PlayStation 4 and I can't download it?

Comment: Some PS3 games are available through PSNow which you can play on PS4. You don't download the PS3 games, but you stream them (meaning you need to be online to play). PSNow games are available to rent individually or via a monthly/yearly subscription which gives you access to a wide variety of PS3 and PS4 games (something like 500+ games).

Answer (score 2):

You can buy a PS3 Game from the Playstation Store, but when you try to download it, it won't let you download it on your PS4, as PS3 games are not compatible with PS4.